# We are twins. Who are we?

Tags: riddle

We are twins
We are the gateway of silence
We enrich your world, but you can live without us.
We are your friends, but sometimes we can be loud when you don't want us to be.
Sometimes we annoy you, but you will never want to lose us.

Who or what are we?

---

New hint:

> Sometimes we can be blocked, but that is only temporary.

Another new hint:

> We are usually dry but sometimes we flood.

3rd new hint (this hint almost gives it away, but I can't resist):

> Some children think we provide food, but we don't.

I will give a new hint for every wrong answer.

Comment: two ears, you can live without them, we hear good things that enrich our life, they are by your side like friends, sometimes we hear loud noice that disturbs us in our work, sometimes we get itchy feeling in the ears that annoys us, but we don't want to lose them

Comment: two brain halves. Obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> **Two nostrils.**

We are twins

> We have two of them

We are the gateway of silence

> You usually have your mouth closed when you breathe with your nose, not speaking.

We enrich your world, but you can live without us.

> We smell good aroma with them, but living without nose is possible

We are your friends, but sometimes we can be loud when you don't want us to be.

> Sometimes we sneeze and make a very loud sound

Sometimes we annoy you, but you will never want to lose us.

> Sometimes we get itchy, tingling feelings inside them that annoy us

Hints:

> We can block them but, however, only for few moments and sometimes we have a cold that makes our nostrils runny with mucus. Some kids have a habit of eating solid mucus of their own!

Comment: Yuck! But I think it's correct.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is right, but it fits the hints.

> Your ears are twins.
>  They allow you to detect silence.
>  They enrich your world (music!) but you can live without them.
>  If you have tinnitus, they can be loud when you don't want.
>  They annoy you if you are in hearing range of Nickelback, but you don't want to lose them.
>  You can put your fingers in your ears, but not forever.

Comment: Very clever, but not the answer I am thinking of.  I will write another clue.

Comment: Why aren’t earholes called earstrils? :-)

Comment: Or the nostrils called noseholes?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> The nostrils

We are twins

> There are 2 nostrils.

We are the gateway of silence

> Nostrils usually don't make any noise.

We enrich your world, but you can live without us.

> Pleasant smells enrich our world, but we can live without the sense of smell.

We are your friends, but sometimes we can be loud when you don't want us to be.

> If you have a cold, you may sniffle a lot.  Also, nostril problems can cause snoring.

Sometimes we annoy you, but you will never want to lose us.

> Sometimes dried mucus in the nostrils can be annoying.

Sometimes we can be blockaded, but that is only temporary.

> If you have a cold, you may have nasal congestion.

We are usually dry but sometimes we flood.

> Your nose may be runny if you have a cold, but your nostrils are usually dry otherwise.

Comment: good job, just a minute or so too late or I would of flagged your answer as the correct one..  :-)

Answer (score 0):

We are twins right and left
We are the gateway of silence doesnt normally make noise
We enrich your world, but you can live without us.

> If none u can be operated to open it.

We are your friends, but sometimes we can be loud when you don't want us to be.

> For friends dont wanna say it but loud farts in front of people.

Sometimes we annoy you, but you will never want to lose us.

> opps need to go cr but never lose them cuz its weird.

Sometimes we can be blockaded, but that is only temporary.

> hold ur poop.

We are usually dry but sometimes we flood.

> poop is dry   diarrhea is wer flood.

ANSWER IS:

> BUTT BOTTOCKS RIGHT AND LEFT

Comment: lmao.  no.  sorry.

Comment: sad it would be funny if yes

Comment: this...actually fits all the clues.  Except the last hint.

Comment: How the hell did three people upvote this?

Answer (score 0):

> I think the answer is the vocal folds in our neck. They are gateway to our silence. We can live without them. They sometimes make a louder sound than we want to. They sometimes get blocked.

Comment: no.. but kudos for trying

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's

> Ears

because

> They enrich our world, can be noisy when we don't want them to be (they recieve all noise so everything noisy has to come through them) and though you can get annoyed by noises you'd never want to loose your ears. Even to hear silence, you must have ears (thus gateways).

P.S. I checked the hints. I am absolutely correct. The only other candidate are nostrils, which don't make sense as they are not the gateways of silence.

All the internets please.

Comment: nostrils are the gateways of silence because, people who close their mouths, breathe through their nose.  People who speaking or shouting, breathe with their mouth.  But ears are a good guess, someone else also guessed that earlier. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

We are twins

> Left and right brain half.

We are the gateway of silence

> If you want to be quiet, you need our approval.

We enrich your world, but you can live without us.

> This one is obvious.

We are your friends, but sometimes we can be loud when you don't want us to be.

> Voices in you head.

Sometimes we annoy you, but you will never want to lose us.